# elasticsearch get uniqe properties

Tags: elasticsearch

is it possible to query elastic and get the uniqe properties? 
for example:
if I have 3 documents in index:

```
{
"number": 3
"name": "larry",
"lastName":"ck"
},
{
"number": 5
"name": "one",
"lastName": "two"
"age":33
},
{
"number": 22
"name": "a",
"lastName": "b"
"age": 33,
"gender": "male"
}
```

I want to get unique properties of all documents with "number" between `1-10` (only 2 documents are fitted)

```
result = [number, name, lastName, age]
```

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question? You just have to querry with a GT and LT range no ? What is your problem?

Comment: if I will query with GT and LT I will receive 2 documents (the first and the second documents), I need only the keys names, without duplicate, so my expected result should be: [number, name, lastName, age]  and thats it.

Comment: 1) filter if you have too (between gap, term wathever) 2) aggregate on the field you want to, to eleminate duplicate, 3) use post filter to keep only field you want.

Comment: I'm not completely understand, can you post Answer with some example please?

Comment: I need to aggregate all fields and to get all keys (without value), is it possible?
can you post some example?

Answer (score 0):

size = 0 cause i dont want the docs result (as you wish)

The first agg (groupby) is a groupby, specify what s is a duplicate for you in this part
The subagg (remove_dup) will only keep the first element from the first add groupby
The source array will draw the field you specify (and wont print all of them).

Hope it s what you are looking for !

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fieldkey"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "remove_dup": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": [
              "field1",
              "field34"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: as mentioned, I donk know the "fieldkey", I need all keys..
if I run your query as is, the result is: 
 {
  "took": 110,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2857236,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}

Comment: build your own duplicate search function then, and use it in the groupby: "duplicateCount": {"terms": {
      "script": "doc['field1'].values + doc['field2'].values+doc['field3'].values"
    },

Comment: still you suggest solution with specific fieldName ('field1'), do you have some example for generic code? because I dont know thr fields name